# Como enviar un JSON en una Solicitud GET Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest

Es posible enviar un Objeto **JSON** en una solicitud GET sea por *JQUERY* o *XMLHttpRequest* o *Fetch* etc...
digamos por el **BODY** como se haría en un **POST**.

Si no, como procesar aquellas solicitudes donde los parámetros o la cadena que se envia por GET(QueryString o Parameters)son muy largas y producen este error HTTP status code 414.

realice una prueba con un cliente **Postman** mandando una petición **GET** con *payload* y con **Fiddler** vi la petición y parece que si tiene *payload*, pero en *chrome*,*firefox* el contenido pareciera vació.

Comment: y por que no hacer una petición POST?? la petción POST tambien te devuelve algo

Comment: Si estas haciendo un GET con demasiados parámetros debes de revisar bien lo que haces y replantearte la solución

Comment: No tengo control del API esta como GET, los paramentos son como 4 pero estos están codificados en Base64

Comment: Que te dice la documentación de la API?

Comment: la acción dice que es GET, y como payload 
[base64_1,base64_2...] es un array y devuelve un array igual codificado en base64 pero firmados.

Comment: NO es posible *enviar un Objeto JSON en una solicitud GET sea por JQUERY o XMLHttpRequest o Fetch etc... digamos por el BODY como se haría en un POST*. El motivo es que las peticiones GET no tienen cuerpo. Todo lo que vayas a enviar por GET tiene que ser en forma URLencoded, o sea, algo así:  `unaClave=unValor&otraClave=otroValor`

Comment: Entiendo, gracias creo que en lugar de mandar el arreglo lo mando de uno en uno dentro de un loop. aunque hay unos documentos muy largos. donde el servicio me retorna 414.

Comment: No tienes que mandarlo uno a uno, puedes mandar todo lo que quieras hasta el límite permitido en cuanto a tamaño, de hecho en mi comentario anterior se estaban enviando dos valores asociados cada uno a su clave. Si quieres formar un JSON en el servidor puedes hacer una conversión desde el array en que se convierten los datos, dependiendo del lenguaje de programación con el que vayas a trabajar en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Por definición [el método `GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) no tiene cuerpo en la petición, por tanto, todos los valores que se envían por `GET` deben viajar en la URL. Por tanto, NO es posible enviar un JSON en la solicitud con el método GET.

Otra cosa es la respuesta, que sí puede traer un JSON, pero ese es otro asunto.

Lo que sí puedes es convertir los datos enviados mediante GET en un JSON, pero eso no significa que estás enviando un JSON por GET, sino que **estás convirtiendo** lo enviado por GET en un JSON.

Veamos un ejemplo:

Si en la URL tu pasas estos datos:

```
id=1&name=Pedro&lastname=Pérez
```

Estos datos son convertidos en un array en el servidor.

En el caso de PHP, en la superglobal `$_GET`, que es donde se reciben los datos pasados por el método GET vas a tener esto:

```
$_GET=array(
                'id'=>1,
                'name'=>'Pedro',
                'lastname'=>'Pérez'
            );
```

Si quieres **convertirlo a JSON** en el contexto de PHP, sería tan simple como esto:

```
$json=json_decode(json_encode($_GET));
```

Probamos si hay un objeto bien creado:

```
var_dump($json);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Pedro"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(6) "Pérez"
}
```

Y podemos leer cualquiera de sus propiedades, por ejemplo:

```
echo $json->id. " ".$json->name." ".$json->lastname;
```

**Salida:**

```
1 Pedro Pérez
```

En cuanto al error 414, éste ocurre cuando mandas un URI demasiado largo ([ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414)).

Si la API que quieres consultar no depende de ti, debes verificar en su documentación o contactando al soporte técnico, si es posible enviar peticiones POST a la misma. Si depende de ti entonces lo propio sería habilitarla para que reciba peticiones POST, pues este es el verdadero problema aquí, ya que el método propio para enviar datos es POST.

Comment: por lo que se detalla en la pregunta, el usuario utiliza una API (que no es de el) y requiere enviar los parámetros por la url pero obtiene un error 414